C++ regex how to match start of line, not just start of string?
How do I match a regex when it appears at the start of a line, even when it might not necessarily be at the start of the string?
My goal is to be able to use regex to find all instances of #include <file.ext> in a string, so that I can replace them with the contents of the file. (Basically, emulating what C++ does with header files.)
void main() {
    std::string src =
            "#include <abc.xyz>\n"
            "This is not an include.\n"
            "This #include <should.be> ignored.\n"
            "#include <def.xyz>\n"
            "This is also not an include.";

    std::regex spec(R"(^#include[\s]+<[a-zA-z0-9_.]+>)");
    std::smatch match;

    // Print all matches.
    std::cout << "[Print Start]" << std::endl;
    std::string::const_iterator iter(src.cbegin());
    while (iter != src.end()) {
        std::regex_search(iter, src.cend(), match, spec);
        if (!match.ready()) { continue; }
        std::cout << match.str() << std::endl;
        iter = match.suffix().first;
    }
    std::cout << "[Print End]" << std::endl;
}

Currently the output is #include <abc.xyz>.
But I want the output to be #include <abc.xyz> and #include <def.xyz>.

std::regex spec(R"((?:^|\n)(#include\s+<[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+>))"); and then std::cout << match.str(1) << std::endl;

It would make more sense if you had a vector of lines. The iterate over the lines in the vector, and check if it's a match or not.

Specify the multiline syntax flag when constructing the regex:
std::regex spec(R"(^#include[\s]+<[a-zA-z0-9_.]+>)", std::regex::ECMAScript | std::regex::multiline);

